# How to get the endorsement from multiple peers by using command line to invoke the transaction

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How to get the endorsement from multiple peers by using command line to invoke the transaction? Now the example e2e_cli only shows us get the endorsement from one peer. 
The command like, CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0:7051 peer chaincode invoke -C myc -n mycc -v v0 -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented. 
If you want CLI-like usage with a binary you can easily transfer across machines consider using the [go-SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I have been using java sdk to do the dev work, which supports to get the endorsement from multiple servers, but sometimes I will use command line to do some quick testing.

Comment: fabric-sdk-go isn't too hard to use.
Also check out https://github.com/securekey/fabric-examples/tree/master/fabric-cli

Answer (score 0):

In the past, peer CLI could only collect an endorsement from a single peer when submitting a transaction. A simple hack has been proposed to address this requirement in Hyperledger JIRA in the [following issue report](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9446). The hack is described as the following command.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCerts  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCerts /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}' >&log.txt
```